# Unusual a:hover behavior (IE 8)

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a nav menu that changes the background color on hover. Below are two images. The first image shows the behavior that I have in all browsers but IE 8 (haven't tested anything below 8). The second image shows the behavior in IE 8. I would like IE 8 to look like everything else (filling the nav bar). I've also posted the CSS and ASP.Net for the menu. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

[image]

ASP.Net

```
<ul id="mainNav" runat="server">
    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Vendors.aspx">Our Vendors</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Customer Support</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Technical Assistance</asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li><asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl="SalesExecutives.aspx">AMS Sales Assistance</asp:HyperLink></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#mainNav {
    float: right;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

ul#mainNav li {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #746935;
    float: left;
}

ul#mainNav li a {
    color: #746935;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 8px 9px 8px;
}

ul#mainNav li a:hover, ul#mainNav li a.active {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #746935;
    padding: 8px 8px 9px 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `a` elements `display: block`:

```
ul#mainNav li a {
    display: block;

    color: #746935;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 8px 9px 8px;
}
```

Comment: That was an embarrassingly easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try to set line-height to the height you need